# Get selected value from a ComboBox which is already in the excel sheet (VBA)

Tags: vba

How do I get the selected value and use it in a macro? Because my problem is that I already have the ComboBox on the sheet, so I cannot create the ComboBox and assign the macro automatically. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the Combobox is on the worksheet,

1. go to developer tab and click on Design Mode in controls group
2. Right click on the Combobox and click on Format control
3. Note the cell address on the Cell link range selection control

Use this value to access value from the Macro.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ankur, thanks for the answer. I really don't understand why the Format Control does not appear, even if I did what you suggested (clicking on the design mode). Any idea about this?